# How to use a windows forms embedded resource as the Source for a WPF mediaelement?

Tags: wpf, winforms, mediaelement, elementhost

I am hosting a MediaElement in a WinForms application, which I would like to play both images and video through.  My images and video are set as embedded resources to the application.

The MediaElement.Source property only accepts a URI.

Any ideas on how to get the MediaElement to play the embedded resourece files without writing them to disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement cannot play from embedded resources files.  It would be possible by writing your own DirectShow source filter, but that might be a lot of work for little benefit.